# Sequence contains no elements errror - MVC (Models and Data Access)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, view, error-handling, model

I'm trying to follow the [MVC Music Store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4) , but I got an error which I can't handle. I've created the action:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string category)
        {
            using (OnlineStoreDbContext db = new OnlineStoreDbContext())
            {
                // Get category and its associated products
                var categoryModel = db.Categories.Include("Products")
                    .Single(c => c.Title == category);
                return View(categoryModel);
            }
        }
```

Than I created and the respective View:

```
@model OnlineStoreMVC.Core.Models.Category
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}

<h2>Browse Category: @Model.Title</h2>

<ul>
    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
    {
        <li>
            @product.Title
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

But when I try to open: `http://localhost:51642/Store/Browse?cat=Action`, I get error:

`"Sequence contains no elements"` regarding this line:

```
    var categoryModel = db.Categories.Include("Products")
.Single(c => c.Title == category);
```

I've alredy tried to replace Single with SingleOrDefault, but then the error was
`"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."` regarding that line in the View: `"<h2>Browse Category: @Model.Title</h2>"`

Comment: What's the value of 'category' ? check that with debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing cat as key in you're url and it should be category. So you should call `http://localhost:51642/Store/Browse?category=Action`

About the the error "Object reference not set to an instance of the object" you have to change you Action method to:

```
public ActionResult Browse(string category)
{
   using (OnlineStoreDbContext db = new OnlineStoreDbContext())
   {
        // Get category and its associated products
        var categoryModel = db.Categories.Include("Products")
            .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Title == category);

        if (categoryModel == default(Category))
        {
            categoryModel = new Category();
            categoryModel.Products = new List<Product>();
        }

        return View(categoryModel);
   }
}
```